# Beautiful Soup: Remove Tags that only contain href

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

From BeautifulSoup I'm getting a list back of specific tags, some of the tags only contains links, no further text. When I use the `get_text()` method on these, I get the description of the links.

But when the tag *only* contains a `<a href>` element, I want to ignore it.

```
Tag: <p class="abc">text1 <a href=...>desc</a> text2</p> -> result: text1 desc text2 (OKAY)

Tag: <p class="abc"><a href=...>desc</a></p> -> result: desc (NOT OKAY)
```

When the tag only contains a link, I want to filter them out. How can I do that?

Comment: You'll get more useful answers if you can supply some example input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over `p` tags and check if there is only one child containing the `a` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div>
    <p class="abc">text1 <a href='http://mysite1.com'>desc1</a> text2</p>
    <p class="abc"><a href='http://mysite2.com'>desc2</a></p>
    <p class="abc"><a href='http://mysite3.com'>desc3</a>text3</p>
    <p class="abc">text4<a href='http://mysite4.com'>des4</a></p>
    <p class="abc">text5</p>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for p in soup('p', class_='abc'):
    if len(p.contents) == 1 and p.contents[0].name == 'a':
        print p
```

prints:

```
<p class="abc"><a href="http://mysite2.com">desc2</a></p>
```

FYI, [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) contains the list of tag's children.